# can konvajs detect all overlapped object?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I want to run all click event in object even if the object overlapped another one. How can I get ALL object that my mouse point(not only uppermost one, but also behind another object) like RayCastAll in Unity?

Comment: Get the event click (x,y) and walk your shapes doing a hit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function `stage.getAllIntersections(pos)`

https://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.Stage.html#getAllIntersections